# how to debug GWT 2.4 in sigel with eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, deployment

Exists some way to do hot redeploy when developing with gwt 2.4 in eclipse so i can make some change in the view like the text of a label and then press refresh or something like that and the modification appear? that problem is because the project i'm running takes at least 50 minutes to compile and wait 50 minutes just for one text of a label for example is hard...

Answer (score 1):

Well ok, you're question is somewhat vague, but here's some points that hopefuly will help:

1. Yep, GWT compilation is slow. If you have a big GWT project, it might take good minutes for it to compile. This is sort of a known issue. What you can do to solve this is split your project into multiple GWT libraries and just compile the library you're currently working with.
2. Regarding hot deploy: your gwt project has two types of code: client code and server side code. The client side code (which is translated to Javascript by the GWT compiler) is hot-deployable. If you follow the instructions here:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/gettingstarted

you'll have a "magic button" that lets you hot deploy your project into any of the more popular browsers. This means that you can modify your client-side code, refresh your browser and it's updated.

For the server-side code that doesn't work. AFAIK, you need to re-compile your project for those modification to be taken into account.

Comment: i tired this site, but did not help... i just want to change something in the client side (a text label por exempla) and have not to recompile all the project that takes 50 minutes to see the change...

Comment: Normally, you should be able to do just that (change a text label in your client code, refresh browser, see the change, no compilation needed) by simply following the official install instructions. I've tried that, it works. Maybe I'm not understanding what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried GWT Designer?

Read more : https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/